# How can I instruct buildr to download all javadocs?

Tags: javadoc, buildr

When running `buildr eclipse` builder generates (among others) following entry in `.classpath`:

```
<classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/com/sun/jersey/jersey-core/1.12/jersey-core-1.12.jar" sourcepath="M2_REPO/com/sun/jersey/jersey-core/1.12/jersey-core-1.12-sources.jar" javadocpath="M2_REPO/com/sun/jersey/jersey-core/1.12/jersey-core-1.12-javadoc.jar"/>
```

The javadoc.jar, however, is missing in M2_REPO. How can I instruct buildr to download all javadocs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `buildr artifacts:javadoc` to download the javadocs for all referenced dependencies. `buildr artifacts:sources` downloads all sources, `buildr artifacts` downloads both.